# python bytes() in serialport2 with node.js

Tags: python, node.js, serial-port

I am trying to get a python script to write to a serial port with pyserial, to node.js using serialport2.

I am very confused about `bytes()` in python, wonder can anyone give me a hand?

python:

```
ser.write(bytes(chr(160))
ser.write(bytes(chr(157))
```

so how do I do this in node.js?

serialport2 used in node.js is located [here](https://github.com/joeferner/node-serialport2/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the bytes() cast isn't required in the Python code. Anyway, are you asking how to read the data into node.js with serialport2?

Comment: I am trying to write to serial port by serialport2 in node.js, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [node-serialport2 readme](https://github.com/joeferner/node-serialport2/blob/master/README.md):

> **write(buffer, [callback])**
>
> Writes data to the serial port.
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - `buffer` - This can be a node Buffer object or a string.
> - `callback(err, byteWritten)` - Callback called after writing bytes.

So, you can give a string object or Buffer object as the argument. A [Buffer object](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers) will probably do what you want (send integer values):

> `var buffer = new Buffer([ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]);`
>
> This initializes the buffer to the contents of this array. Keep in mind that the contents
>   of the array are integers representing bytes.

For your data, it would be:

```
var buffer = new Buffer([160, 157]);
```

By the way, you don't need to do any special casting in Python with PySerial. From the [PySerial API documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html):

> **write(data)**
>
> - Parameters: `data` – Data to send.
> - Returns: Number of bytes written.
> - Raises SerialTimeoutException: In case a write timeout is configured for the port and the time is exceeded.
>
> Write the string data to the port.
>
> *Changed in version 2.5: Accepts instances of bytes and bytearray when
>   available (Python 2.6 and newer) and str otherwise.*

Note the "changed in version 2.5" note.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you search `String.fromCharCode(code)` to convert a character code to a string in JS.

Try this with serialport2:

```
port.write(String.fromCharCode(160, 157));
```